# Film about a time travel ring

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I am fairly sure that this film is not in the English language. I think it was French, but perhaps not. It was low budget. I watched it in 1981, and it did not seem to be a 1960s or earlier movie, so that limits it to the 1970s.

Right at the start it shows a confusing series of blurry shots, with a red wash, suggestive of the controls of a spacecraft. Then it shows a big splash - intended to be the spacecraft crashing in the ocean (but clearly something like a stick of dynamite thrown from the beach - it was low budget). A man crawls onto the beach.

The only high tech prop is a ring. It is worn by the space traveler as a survival device. It can move him forward in time but not backward in time. He is searching for a time when the Earth technology becomes advanced enough that he can build a spacecraft and go home. He seems to be in South America. He meets what might be conquistadors, and is strung upside down on a wooden frame by them. He pretends to bribe one of the guards with his ring. It won't come off. He says to twist it - which sends him through time.

Several trips later, in the second half of the 20th century, he meets a girl. He likes her. She wants to come with him through time. He wonders whether holding onto her when he twists the ring will bring her too. It does, but she is immediately shot, as he has landed in a modern war zone. Sad at the death he twists the ring again - but this time the camera does not follow him. End of movie.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "He is chasing a time"?

Comment: Nothing philosophical - I just mean that he wishes to move forward in time until the technology of the Earth has advanced to the point that he can build a space ship with it.

Comment: Possibly the same film; https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=46964

Comment: Unfortunately not. Apart from knowing all the films mentioned in the link - the device was definitely ring, and a ring alone: no implication of any other machine. And it could only go forward, not backward. That was a strong theme in the film.

Comment: Can you clarify the approximate year or decade in which you actually saw this movie? You say _"perhaps 1970s"_ in the first line of the description, but it's unclear if that's when you watched it, or just an estimate of when you think it was made.

Comment: @LogicDictates Thanks, I am still keen to find this movie again. From contextual clues (the lady I watched it with and where) I would have watched it in 1981. It might just possibly have been a 1960s film, but it did not have the feel of such. Hence 1970s.